# Extract id from url string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to extract the id `1406570408` from the below url. I was wondering if there is a better way than my current try ?

```
let str = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';

str = str.split('/')
str = str[5].split('?')

console.log(str[0]) // 1406570408
```

Comment: I can only imagine minimizing the steps into one step as follows:

console.log(((str.split('/'))[5].split('?'))[0])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about using url class ?

```
let url = new URL("https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013")

url.pathname.split('/')[3] //equals the id
```

here
`url.pathname` contains `webapp/viewer/1406570408`

or use

`url.pathname.split('/').pop()` to remove the last element as [@O.Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205608/o-jones) pointed out

Comment: And if you know you want the very last item in the path, the number, you can do `const str = url.pathname.split('/').pop()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = "https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?pag…-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013"

const url2 = "https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408"

const url3 = "https://www.google.de/webapp/something/1406570408"

const getId = (url) => {
  const match = /(?<=viewer\/)\d*/.exec(url)
  return match ? match[0] : null;

}

console.log(getId(url))
console.log(getId(url2))
console.log(getId(url3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';

const segments = new URL(url).pathname.split('/');
const last = segments.pop() || segments.pop(); 
console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the single line plain javascript methods of Arrays

```
let str = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';
str = str.split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[0]
console.log(str) // 1406570408
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';
console.log(str.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

```html
Use an regrex to find an numeric value inside a url string
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to parse the URL with the [URL JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), and then extract the piece of data you need from the `pathname` property provided to you by the `URL`.

An example for your usecase:

```js
let str = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';

let url = new URL(str);                          // create an instance of the URL API
let pathname = url.pathname;                     // pathname property
let segments = pathname.split('/');              // split pathname by / slash
let last_item = segments.slice(-1)[0] || null;   // grab the last item from pathname array

console.log(last_item);
```

Your output will be: `1406570408`.

If your pathname is `'/'` or no pathname at all, you'll receive a `null` which you can handle later.

Also, the above code could be shortened into:

```js
let str = 'https://www.google.de/webapp/viewer/1406570408?page=1&pageType=DE-P-Global_Startpage&lat=52.5517268&lng=13.4123013';

let last_item = (new URL(str)).pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0] || null;

console.log(last_item);
```